# Convert dictionary to dataframe python

Tags: python, database, pandas

How to read the file as a dataframe in pandas python?

The file contains the following

```
{"headers": {"ai5": "8fa683e59c02c04cb781ac689686db07", "debug": null, "random": null, "sdkv": "7.6"}, "post": {"event": "ggstart", "ts": "1462759195259"}, "params": {}, "bottle": {"timestamp": "2016-05-09 02:00:00.004906", "game_id": "55107008"}}
{"headers": {"ai5": "335644267c1d5f04eaea7bc6f51b1861", "debug": null, "random": null, "sdkv": "7.6"}, "post": {"event": "ggstart", "ts": "1462759189745"}, "params": {}, "bottle": {"timestamp": "2016-05-09 02:00:00.033775", "game_id": "55107008"}}
```

....many rows below

How can I load it into a dataframe, dictionary keys as headers ?

Comment: Is this how the file looks like? So it is a file where the rows are JSON entries?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ,yes this is how the file looks like, it is .log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use python's `open` + `readlines` to create the `pd.Series` object, then use a combination of `json.loads` and `json_normalize`

```
import json
import pandas as pd

pd.io.json.json_normalize(
    pd.Series(open('file.json').readlines()).apply(json.loads))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) with parameter `lines=True` first:

```
df = pd.read_json('file.json', lines=True)
print (df)
                                              bottle  \
0  {'timestamp': '2016-05-09 02:00:00.004906', 'g...   
1  {'timestamp': '2016-05-09 02:00:00.033775', 'g...   

                                             headers params  \
0  {'ai5': '8fa683e59c02c04cb781ac689686db07', 'r...     {}   
1  {'ai5': '335644267c1d5f04eaea7bc6f51b1861', 'r...     {}   

                                          post  
0  {'event': 'ggstart', 'ts': '1462759195259'}  
1  {'event': 'ggstart', 'ts': '1462759189745'}
```

And then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) nested `dictionaries`, output is `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[x].values.tolist()) for x in df], axis=1, keys=df.columns)
print (df)
     bottle                                                       headers  \
    game_id                   timestamp                               ai5   
0  55107008  2016-05-09 02:00:00.004906  8fa683e59c02c04cb781ac689686db07   
1  55107008  2016-05-09 02:00:00.033775  335644267c1d5f04eaea7bc6f51b1861   

                        post                 
  debug random sdkv    event             ts  
0  None   None  7.6  ggstart  1462759195259  
1  None   None  7.6  ggstart  1462759189745
```

Slowier solution with `apply(pd.Series)`

```
df = pd.concat([df[x].apply(pd.Series) for x in df], axis=1, keys=df.columns)
print (df)
     bottle                                                       headers  \
    game_id                   timestamp                               ai5   
0  55107008  2016-05-09 02:00:00.004906  8fa683e59c02c04cb781ac689686db07   
1  55107008  2016-05-09 02:00:00.033775  335644267c1d5f04eaea7bc6f51b1861   

                        post                 
  debug random sdkv    event             ts  
0  None   None  7.6  ggstart  1462759195259  
1  None   None  7.6  ggstart  1462759189745
```

For remove `MultiIndex` add `map`:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[x].values.tolist()) for x in df], axis=1, keys=df.columns)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
  bottle_game_id            bottle_timestamp  \
0       55107008  2016-05-09 02:00:00.004906   
1       55107008  2016-05-09 02:00:00.033775   

                        headers_ai5 headers_debug headers_random headers_sdkv  \
0  8fa683e59c02c04cb781ac689686db07          None           None          7.6   
1  335644267c1d5f04eaea7bc6f51b1861          None           None          7.6   

  post_event        post_ts  
0    ggstart  1462759195259  
1    ggstart  1462759189745
```

Comment: Thank you @jazrael . Your answer works. This was my first question at StackOverflow and got the answer in 30 mins, It is great.